# adjacency matrix implementation in c

Tags: c, data-structures, graph

I am trying to implement a graph using adjacency matrix i am confused in memory allocation of 2d array 
will it be correct `G->adj=(int**)malloc(sizeof(G->v*G->V))`
or the below one is correct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Graph{
 int V;
 int E;
 int **adj;
};
struct Graph* adjmatrix(){
 int u,v,i;
 struct Graph* G=(struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
 if(!G)
     printf("Memory Null");
 printf("enter the number of vertex and edges");
 scanf("%d %d",&G->V,&G->E);
 G->adj=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*( G->V * G->V ));
 for(u=0;u<G->V;u++){
     for(v=0;v<G->V;v++){
         G->adj[u][v]=0; 

    }
}

for(i=0;i<G->V;i++){
    printf("reading edge");
    scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
    G->adj[u][v]=1;
    G->adj[v][u]=1;

}
return G;
}
```

Comment: You’re only allocating one memory block, not a 2D array. You don’t even need a 2D array since it’s not jagged, you can use a 1D array instead and make it easier.

Comment: Please sir can u tell me the code

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(G->v*G->V))` is certainly wrong.  Same as `malloc(sizeof(int))`

Comment: can you write the answer below so that i can properly understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store your matrix by using pointer to pointer `int** adj` you need to allocate memory for rows in first step, then allocate memory for columns:

```
  // create G->V rows
  G->adj=(int**)malloc( sizeof(int*) * G->V);
  // for every row create G->V columns
  for (int i = 0; i < G->V; ++i)
     G->adj[i] = (int*)malloc (sizeof(int) * G->V);
```

Another approach to store your adjacency matrix is create 1D array but then you need to use `u * G->V + v` formula to access `(u,v)` item:

Declare in `Graph`:

```
 int *adj;
```

allocate memory

```
 G->adj=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ( G->V * G->V));
```

and access elements

```
G->adj[ u*G->V + v ] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to allocate memory for a 2D array in C. Tailored specifically to your code, you can do either of the following:

**Allocating memory for each row separately:**

Start by allocating memory for an array of pointers, one for each row and allocate memory for an array of integers using each of these pointers.

```
// Pointer array of rows
G->adj = (int **)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int *));

// Allocate memory for each row
for (int i = 0; i < G->V; i++)
    G->adj[i] = (int *)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int));
```

**Allocating memory at once and reorient:**

Start by allocating memory for an array of pointers, one for each row and allocate enough memory to store a full matrix using the first pointer. You then reorient each of the pointers in the array to point to each row of this allocated space.

```
// Pointer array of rows
G->adj  = (int **)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int *)); 

// Allocate enough space for a matrix
G->adj[0] = (int *)malloc(G->V * G->V *sizeof(int)); 

// Use each pointer to point to a block G->V distance
// from the previous pointer
for(i = 0; i < G->V; i++) 
    G->adj[i] = (*G->adj + G->V * i);
```